# Is there an aternative to PhoneTextAccentStyle in Windows Universal App (even if only in Phone)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

When working in Windows Phone 8.0 I always use

```
<TextBlock  Text="Text in Phone's Accent Color"
            Style ="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}"/>
```

to display text in the users chosen accent style.

But I am unable to find a `TextBlock` style in Windows Phone 8.1 / Universal that does the same.

Is there an alternative to `PhoneTextAccentStyle` in Windows Universal apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has changed to a `ThemeResource`

```
<TextBlock Text="I'm a textbox" Foreground="{ThemeResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! These changes are getting on my nerve